# $G$ is simple, connected and planar graph on $22$ vertices then $G$ has at most $30$ edges.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on $22$ vertices. $G$ is simple, connected and planar. It does not have a circuit of length $4$. Furthermore, the dual of $G$ has an Euler circuit.

To prove that $G$ has at most $30$ edges.

---

I am not getting an idea to proceed with the problem.

From the condition of the planar graph, we have $e \le 3v-6$. I am not able to use the fact that the dual of $G$ has an Euler circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual graph of $G$ has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every face of $G$ has an **even** number of sides (recall that in the dual graph, each vertex is a face of $G$ and its degree is the number of sides of the face).

Let $f_k$ be the number of faces with $k$ sides. By assumption $f_2=0$ (the graph is simple), and $f_4=0$ (no circuit of length 4). So each face has at least $6$ sides.

Moreover, since the sum of the number of sides of the faces equals twice the number of edges, it follows that
$$2e=\sum_{k\geq 6}kf_{k}\geq 6\sum_{k\geq 6}f_{k}=6f\implies \frac{e}{3}\geq f.$$
Finally, by Euler's formula with $v=22$, we have that $22-e+f=2$ and we find
$$e=20+f\leq 20 +\frac{e}{3}\implies \frac{2e}{3}\leq 20\implies e\leq 30.$$